# Hadoop map-reduce : Order of records while grouping

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a record in each line of input and each record has around 10 fields. First, I group the records by three fields `(field1, field2, field3)` thus one mapper/reducer is responsible for one unique group (based on the three fields). Within each group, I sort the records based on another integer field `timestamp` and I tag each record in the group with the same tag `aTag` by adding another field.

Lets say that in mapper#1, I tag a sorted group as `aTag` and in mapper#2, I tag another group (a different group because I initially grouped the records based on the three fields) with the same tag `aTag`.

Now, if I group the records based on the tag field (i.e., grouping the groups in different mappers), I notice that the ordering within each group is no more preserved. I was expecting that since each mapper has a group with all records having the same tag, grouping by the tag name should just involve getting the relevant groups from other mappers and just concatenating them without re-ordering each individual group.

Is it because I am trying to store the records in gzip format and hence it tries to re-order the records for better compression? Also I would like to know how to preserve the order after grouping by the tag name.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are trying to implement the sort step of MapReduce yourself in local memory, but then it completely ignores what you did and re-sorts the items in each group anyway. The proper way to fix this would be to specify a comparator on the keys, so that within each partition so that the merged input to the reducer is according to that comparison function. This means that

1. You don't have to do the sorting yourself
2. You don't run out of memory on one machine trying to sort a really large group.

It seems on your case that you'd want to add `timestamp` to the set of keys, tell it to partition on the first three keys, and tell it to sort on the timestamp.

For more information, see the following diagram, and [Where is Sort used in MapReduce phase and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746311/where-is-sort-used-in-mapreduce-phase-and-why)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. Actually I am launching the jobs with pig script. I solved the issue by again sorting the records based on three fields using nested for each construct.

`B = group A by tag;
 C = foreach B {
       sorted = sort A by field1, field2, field3;
       generate flatten(sorted);
     }`